# French pronunciation of Greek letters

Tags: traduction, prononciation

I am reading technical papers which contain many letters from the Greek alphabet. I'm not sure how to pronounce them and having a hard time looking it up. What is the standard French pronunciation of the Greek alphabet?

Answer (score 6):

Most are pronounced "like they are written", i.e. using the French default usage. The *ê* can be pronounced either /e/ or /ɛ/.

*Thêta* is pronounced /tɛta/ or /teta/, *phi* and *khi* are pronounced /fi/ and /ki/.

Only *zêta*, *epsilon* and *upsilon* might be pronounced partially or totally as foreign words, *z* is often realized as /dz/, "-on" is almost never the nasalisation /ɔ̃/ and *u* is often pronounced /œ/: /d͡zɛta/ or /zɛta/, /ɛpsilon/ & /œpsilon/ or /ypsilon/.

*Lambda* is generally pronounced /lãbda/ in France but the alternative /lam(b)da/ can also be heard, depending on the region.

*Psi* is not special but simply pronounced like the beginning of *psychologue*.

Note that *omicron* is always pronounced the French way, with a nasalisation: /omikrɔ̃/, likely because *micron* is already a French world.

Comment: I also would say that « zêta » is pronounced like « tzêta » or « dzêta ».

Comment: @grouah Yes, I forgot that one. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not doubting the pronunciation of upsilon with /œ/, but I've always used it with /y/ and that's what indicated in the TLFi too.

Comment: I'd add lambda too, which can be /lãbda/ or /lam(b)da/ depending on dialect

Comment: @Eauquidort Added, thx.

Comment: I've also always heard upsilon as /ypsilon/ and zeta as /zɛta/ (no 'dz' or 'tz'). I don't know if it's correct but it's definitely a pronunciation you can encounter. After looking it up, TFLi shows [dze-] and [zε-], the [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/z%C3%AAta) \zɛ.ta\, so I'd say both are possible pronunciations.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Thanks, variants added.

Answer (score 1):

[alphabet grec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_grec#Lettres_classiques).

1. ```
    Α   α   alpha
   ```
2. ```
    Β   β   bêta
   ```
3. ```
    Γ   γ   gamma
   ```
4. ```
    Δ   δ   delta
   ```
5. ```
    Ε   ε   epsilon
   ```
6. ```
    Ζ   ζ   zêta
   ```
7. ```
    Η   η   êta
   ```
8. ```
    Θ   θ   thêta
   ```
9. ```
    Ι   ι   iota
   ```
10. ```
    Κ   κ   kappa
    ```
11. ```
    Λ   λ   lambda
    ```
12. ```
    Μ   μ   mu
    ```
13. ```
    Ν   ν   nu
    ```
14. ```
    Ξ   ξ   ksi/xi
    ```
15. ```
    Ο   ο   omicron
    ```
16. ```
    Π   π   pi
    ```
17. ```
    Ρ   ρ   rhô
    ```
18. ```
    Σ   σ   sigma
    ```
19. ```
    Τ   τ   tau
    ```
20. ```
    Υ   υ   upsilon
    ```
21. ```
    Φ   φ/ϕ phi
    ```
22. ```
    Χ   χ   khi/chi
    ```
23. ```
    Ψ   ψ   psi
    ```
24. ```
    Ω   ω   oméga
    ```

Comment: I have never heard the *mi* and *ni* variants, and rarely the *chi* one.

Comment: @jlliagre: Copy/paste error, those are modern greek pronounciation, they come from [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_grec#Lettres_classiques)

Comment: I have no idea how to pronounce many of these such as "psi". There is not an applicable standard French spelling rule that I am aware of. So this answer really just restates the problem for me without answering it.

Comment: @BetterSense Psi would just be read /psi/, much as like pseudo is /psødɔ/ or /psødo/ psoriasis is /psɔrjazis/ and psy is /psi/. Ancient Greek's complex onsets reamin complex in French, so ptérosaure starts with /pt/, gnostique with /gn/, chtonien with /kt/, xylophone with /gz/ and so on.